# How to bind properties in kv language?

Tags: python, data-binding, kivy

This code is aimed to display two kivy sliders. The second slider should move with the first one (but not the opposite). I've a class `DoubleSlider` where the binding is done:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

kivy.require('1.10.0')

Builder.load_string ("""
<Slider>
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: dp(40)

<DoubleSlider@BoxLayout>:
    slider_1: slider_1
    slider_2: slider_2
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Slider
        id: slider_1

    Slider
        id: slider_2
        value: slider_1.value

<UI>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    DoubleSlider:        
""")


class UI(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return UI()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

This is the only solution I've found (in kvlang). However I can't use it, the binding shown is only a sample.

Actually I want to be able to use the position of the first slider in other other objects which have a numerical property (not specifically the second slider of the same `DoubleSlider` object), meaning I'll do the binding case by case in the `<UI>` rule. So I remove the line `value: slider_1.value` and tried to modify the `<UI>` rule like this:

```
<UI>:
    DoubleSlider:
        # Is expected to be equivalent, but doesn't work
        slider_2.value: slider_1.value
```

I've also tried to use `getter('value')` and `setter('value')` to no avail.

**Questions**:

- What am I doing in `<UI>` in term of assignation? (I fear I bind nothing, but I'm just reassigning `slider_2` property instead, because `slider_2` is itself a property, not a regular reference)
- What is the proper way to bind the sliders in `<UI>`? (preferably using only kv lang, unless this is impossible)

Comment: Your code seems fine, and has the expected effect (changing slider_1 also changes slider_2, but not vice-versa).

Comment: @inclement: The code works, but doesn't fulfill my constraint of doing the binding at instance level, and when edited accordingly doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by doing the binding at instance level. That's what I'd call what you've actually done.

Comment: The binding is done in the `<DoubleSlider>` kv rule, it'll be reproduced in all instances of `DoubleSlider`. I want it to be done in `<UI>` rule, so that it can be applied to individual `DoubleSlider` instances in the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify binding during the instantiation, I do not know if it's the best option, but you can use a custom property. This will also allow you to unbind when you want:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

kivy.require('1.10.0')

Builder.load_string ("""
<Slider>
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: dp(40)

<DoubleSlider@BoxLayout>:
    tied: False                 # <<<<<<<<<<
    slider_1: slider_1
    slider_2: slider_2
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Slider
        id: slider_1

    Slider
        id: slider_2
        value: slider_1.value if root.tied else self.value


<UI>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Tied"
        CheckBox:
            on_active: ds.tied = not ds.tied

    DoubleSlider:       
        id: ds
""")


class UI(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return UI()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

[image]

---

**Edit:**

Another option is to create a new property associated with the `value` property of the slider and use the `on_` syntax:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

kivy.require('1.10.0')

Builder.load_string ("""
<Slider>
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: dp(40)

<DoubleSlider@BoxLayout>:
    slider_1: slider_1
    slider_2: slider_2
    value1: slider_1.value
    value2: slider_2.value
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Slider
        id: slider_1

    Slider
        id: slider_2



<UI>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    DoubleSlider:
        on_value1: self.slider_2.value = self.value1

""")


class UI(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return UI()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: @mins I think I have understood... I've another idea, look at my edition.

Comment: Yes, that's a possible solution. I was wondering if a strict kvlang equivalent of Python `slider_1.bind(value=slider_2.setter('value'))` (which works) existed. But maybe what you propose is the closest (or even *is* this equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

> First I'm not sure the binding is done correctly

You've done binding correctly. It's what cool about using kvlang: it allows to bind properties in declarative style.

Binding in kv file:

```
value: slider_1.value
```

And same thing in pure Python:

```
slider_1.bind(value=slider_2.setter('value'))
```

> So I need to bind the properties at the instance level only.

You're actually binding things at instance level: setting `Slider` properties inside `<DoubleSlider@BoxLayout>` in kvlang - is same thing as binding slider values inside `DoubleSlider` instance's constructor in Python.

If you need different bindings depending on conditions for different `DoubleSlider` instances, I am afraid you should use Python to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. +1, and I clarified my question.